# Update NSManagedObjects efficently in CoreData

Tags: objective-c, database, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have a large amount of data, saved using the Core Data Framework. There are always a lot of updates that have to be made. The Problem is that this updates take too much time.

The reason for this is that for each entry in my database I have to make a query to get the corresponding NSObjectModel and then update its attributes. Because there is a lot of data to browse through, it takes a lot of time. If I only create new objects and insert them in my database, this takes much less time, which of course makes sense.

So my question is if there is a more efficient way to do this, because I'm really talking about minutes, not seconds.

Like I said, I have to get objects from the database very often. You can see it in the code below. Maybe this helps to understand where my problem is:

```
while (additiveElement != nil) {            
            //Get Product
            Product *product = [Product productWithID:additivID inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

            //Get ProductLanguage
            ProductLanguage *productLanguage = [ProductLanguage productLanguageWithLanguage:self.currentLanguage andProductID:additivID inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
            productLanguage.language = self.languageEntity;

            product.productID = additivID;
            productLanguage.name = additivName;
            productLanguage.text = additivText;
            productLanguage.product = product;
            product.productFamily = [ProductFamily familyWithID:additivFamilyID inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

            if (productFiles != nil) {                    
                    File *file = [File fileWithName:fileName inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
                    file.fileName = fileName;
                    file.fileSize = fileSize;
                    file.fileDateNew = fileDate;
                    file.fileType = fileType;
                    file.language = [Language languageWithAbbreviation:@"en"  inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
            }
}
```

Comment: Profile your app using instruments, when performing these updates. You may find that a lot of the time is spent sending and processing managed object notifications rather than database access, particularly if you are updating when you have a fetched results controller in place. Don't change any code until you know where the problem is!

Comment: Post some code. Its alot easier to assist when theres code to look at.
One common pitfall with large data operations is too frequent save-operations, which can be solved by processing data in chunks and being observant of notifications as jrturton prescribes.

Comment: It's difficult to post the code for this because there are a lot of thins done. The save operation is only called at the end of the update process, so this should not be the problem.

Comment: Yup - profile first. Invariably our guesses about what part of Core Data is slow turns out to be wrong. Instruments (and dtrace really) FTW!